# How to bind function to window width?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I bind this function to the window width?

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        jQuery('.navbar-header').slideUp("slow");
    } else {
        jQuery('.navbar-header').slideDown("slow");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi. To help get your question answered may I suggest you add some more information to your answer. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service and simply asking people to do so will result in your question being ignored. You have provided some code but have not explained what it produces and how that differs from what you want. Also think about what specific questions or problems you are having.

Comment: `with window width` what do you mean? do you mean when the window width is change?

Comment: in min window width 992px, the function will work.. otherwise the function have to disable.

Answer (score 1):

From your add explain, you can change responsive change your render based on the width of window.So, the only way to do this, is to change the handler.

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  if (jQuery(document).width() < = 992) {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 0)
    {
        jQuery('.navbar-header').slideUp("slow");
    }
    else
    {
        jQuery('.navbar-header').slideDown("slow");
    }
  }
});
```

By this way, If you change the browser width, will change the show of scroll.